# Should questions having lots of downvotes be downvoted further?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

Is down-voting an already heavily down-voted/closed question kind of like kicking a dead horse? Is this bad practice?

Comment: Not if it was a really, really evil horse.

Comment: @Pekka웃, they usually are.

Comment: Why exactly could it be considered a bad practice?

Comment: As long as you down-vote the question because you think it deserves a down-vote, and not because the down-votes given from other users, there isn't anything wrong.