# Suggestion was tagged with status-declined and keep getting downvotes

Tags: discussion, down-votes, declined-flags

I know that here on meta, downvoting mean disagree, but why the people continue downvoting it even after it already was declined?

The OP admited that the suggestion was bad and asked for sorry, but the people ignored and they keep downvoting the question hours after.

This is fair?

Comment: Remember: posts on Meta, like on Stack Overflow and elsewhere, are not just for the benefit of the question asker. They also serve as reference material for future visitors. People downvote the idea to express that they disagree with the feature request, and that is *right and proper*. We can now point others to your post and show them that the idea has been rejected with a very clear opinion from the community. Voting is orthogonal to the `status-` tag in that respect.

Comment: @gnat: except that in this case it is a Meta `feature-request` post. Noone is voting to let the OP know the post is bad. They are voting on  a feature instead. Yup, it is marked `status-declined` but those that still are voting want to make sure that anyone visiting in the future understands what the general consensus is on that feature request.

Comment: good catch @gnat no way to realize that a different context question already exists, but maybe not a duplicate, its the same problem but in another way, or another understanding.

Comment: you are barely right @MartijnPieters but do you think that is fair to the user that already understood that the question was really bad and he keep losing rep and he cant grow up on meta because of that question?

Comment: see also (probably even closer duplicates): [Should questions having lots of downvotes be downvoted further?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183605/should-questions-having-lots-of-downvotes-be-downvoted-further) => [How many down-votes is enough for a user to understand their problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168563/how-many-down-votes-is-enough-for-a-user-to-understand-their-problem)

Comment: @PauloRoberto: One day, meta.stackoverflow.com will be a proper Meta and rep will not count. At all. Until that day, I wouldn't worry too much about reputation. And for every answer upvote you'd earn in the future (provided you create an answer here at some point) will offset 5 such downvotes. That means you only need 3 upvotes to undo most of the downvotes on that one question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters same reasoning applies. User posted "wrong" feature request => got deservedly voted down => realised why is that ("I get it") => downvotes continue => what do they do?

Comment: @gnat: but Meta voting *is* different. The duplicates talk about Stack Overflow's voting patterns and the advice given is not really all that applicable to Meta.

Comment: @MartijnPieters you are barely right again, i agree with you, but the people of course dont like to be downvoted forever they did learn the lesson, and they are a little right about being angry about that because some people like to have recognition and raise the reputation, and too, the people that only help people for helping, that in the past did some mistakes, will not have the reputation that really deserves.

Comment: i see some agreed here on meta, with this question in discussion. Maybe a solution for this will be useful for the two sides.

Comment: @PauloRoberto: Well, you *did* make a mistake; you didn't do your research. That is now reflected in your reputation. But the fear that you'll never gain a proper rep here now is unfounded. If you ask good questions, create helpful answers, your reputation will grow again. It is as simple as that.

Comment: You may be interested in [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201584/separate-vote-in-favour-and-against-a-feature-request) or [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116010/agree-disagree-button-on-meta-or-upvote-downvote-effects-based-on-tags); a proposal to seperate out votes for/against an idea and on the question itself

Comment: However a fair comment that on meta your reputation is partly made of "having good ideas for the site" much like on stack overflow its partly "being good at programming". So ideas which aren't good (even if reasonably stated) perhaps should effect reputation

Comment: @MartijnPieters believe it or not, but recipes from duplicate still apply. Say, if keeping officially declined feature request as-is is _that_ important, this would make a solid justification to request account disassociation - and if it's not critical, asker has full right to convert it to discussion and edit to opposite attitude, like "why it would be bad idea to introduce badges for fast answers" (if done right, such an edit would even keep existing answers fully intact). Maybe one day I will edit an answer in "I get it" to clarify how to adjust it for meta...

Comment: This question is **`marked as duplicate by ...`**, but there is no link or mention of the question it duplicates. It would be helpful to others searching for the answer (in general, not just for this question), to have a link to the duplicated question. Also, how does #2/3/4/5 who voted it as a duplicate decide that if they can't view the unknown duplicate?