# Stop feature requests from hemorrhaging reputation when marked as status-declined

Tags: feature-request, tags, down-votes

When a Meta question is tagged as [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined), allow downvotes to continue, but stop it from affecting the reputation of the user who posted.

Some related questions on the matter include:

- [Suggestion was tagged with status-declined and keep getting downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209410/243192)
- [Should questions having lots of downvotes be downvoted further?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183605/243192)
- [How many down-votes is enough for a user to understand their problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/168563/243192)

Interminable downvoting on poorly received requests and discussions hit new users hard and that's a problem.

Comment: But why only downvotes.  If a post gets a [meta-tag:status-completed] or [meta-tag:status-pending], should upvotes no longer count?

Comment: I think you may be conflating the the purpose of voting compared to the [status-declined] tag. The first reflects the community's feelings; the second, the official position of Stack Exchange. Why should one limit the other?

Comment: Good catch... i did not realized that. @psubsee2003

Comment: @psubsee2003 That should be [status-planned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-planned) or [status-review](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-review)  not [status-pending](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-pending) ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber only because some new users cant start growing here because some bad questions, they keep getting decreased rep for a long long while. And to have some "recognition" here you need to have some reputation, as the name of it says, reputation. And i'm saying that because i did read about that here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/44189/243192

Comment: It's worth noting that you have two very badly recieved questions but your reputation has gone up by 50 today. This is by-design for exactly this reason; your positive contributions count more

Comment: @PauloRoberto: why do you feel your question will receive downvotes from now until eternity? There are only so many of us here on Meta, we cannot vote more than once for a post, and you really didn't get *that* many downvotes? Can you please stop with the unnecessary dread here?

Comment: @PauloRoberto: and I already pointed out: every upvote on an answer counters **five** downvotes. For questions that means every two upvotes. You really are worrying over nothing here, and in the process digging yourself deeper instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters please, calm down, i am here to help not to make jobbery.

Comment: @PauloRoberto: You also need to work on your English. I pointed out before you tend to come over *very* condescending. I fear it is you who needs to calm down a little.

Comment: @Tijesunimi, that might work for answers, but only moderators can make questions CW IIRC.

Comment: Given your recent active participation, perhaps it's good to have a look at [How do I participate on Meta Stack Overflow and not die trying](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying). It might be of some help.

Comment: What @Richard says. There is no problem here, even heavily downvoted suggestions will end up in a positive rep balance if only a *couple* of people agree with it.

Comment: @Bart he's been given the link at least twice today.

Comment: [Richard's point](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/209411/suggestion-for-the-interminable-downvotes-on-bad-questions-even-if-it-is-already#comment670107_209411) is right.  You've had a pretty rough first day...  my count is 52 downvotes vs 12 upvotes, but yet your rep has increased.  And the voting will level out over time.  Stop worrying about it.  The more you try to stop it, the more you will actually cause more downvotes because you keep bringing attention to the post you want to go away.  If you let the post go, it will be forgotten and disappear (mostly) into the abyss.

Comment: The irony of this question is that you have so many downvotes and you want to stop this kind of behavior

Comment: Pro tip: The more you complain about downvotes, the more downvotes you'll receive.

Comment: Stop editing in commentary like you just did about voting on the question. That's for comments, if even that.

Answer (score 14):

> When a question receive from the moderator the tag [status-declined] then, it automatically do not decrease the OP reputation anymore, but the downvotes continues applying.

**Why?**

There are some *massively-upvoted* [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) posts too, you know. Presumably you don't want to stop folks from benefiting from a well-received idea that's been declined - after all, some of them *have* been implemented eventually, changing that status to completed.

**Why** should you be immune from the consequences of the community's dissatisfaction with an idea just because it's currently marked, "won't implement"?

Keep in mind, the difference between a well-regarded request and one that's heavily down-voted can be as simple as a failure on the part of the requester to explain ***why*** the requested change would be beneficial... I think we should be able to keep encouraging such requesters to improve their requests.

The reputation penalty for down-votes is not that high, but it is supposed to sting a *little bit* - ideally, folks try to put sufficient effort in to writing a good request, but if they don't then perhaps a little reminder isn't such a bad thing. If you can improve your request, then the rep benefit from the resulting up-votes will more than make up for it...

Comment: Perhaps there should be a federal Rep Bailout program that you get reimbursed from when you get downvotes.

Comment: @Pekka, so we would get to be "too big to fail" too? Interesting.

Answer (score 6):

I think the problem with this is that this will lead to a slippery slope. If we stop downvotes from occuring when it gets a [status-declined] tag, why not just stop the post from getting upvotes for [status-completed] posts? After all, it has already been implemented so it is useless to upvote it. Furthermore, you suggested that the downvotes will still apply but no rep changes will occur. The problem with this is that then people will complain that this is unfair due to the fact that, even though they are getting downvotes, their reputation is not changing.

In paper it sounds like a good idea but in practice there are too many factors to consider.

Comment: totally agreed with you, but maybe there some considerations to add to the solution and consider about apply it might be nice dont you think?